# php script to send emails by cron job after a day , week ,2 weeks to the registred users

Tags: php

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users");
$date = date_create("2013-03-15");
$reminderSent = false; // Get this value from the db (true or false) $expiryActioned = false; // Get this value from the db (true or false) //if( is_array( $sql ) && count( $sql ) > 0 ) {
if (!$sql) {
    throw new My_Db_Exception('Database error: ' . mysql_error());
}
foreach ($sql as $sq) {
    $regusers = $sq->user_registered;
    // $ID=$sq->ID; date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
    //echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d"); echo $re=date($regusers);
    if ($regusers == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day")) || $regusers == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 day")) || $regusers == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month"))) {
        echo "Hello";
        $expiringDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sq['user_registred']));
    }
    $todayDate = time();
    $reminderDate = strtotime($expiringDate);
    if ($todayDate == $reminderDate && $reminderSent == false && $expiryActioned == false) {
        echo "Sending"; // Send mail     $reminderSent = "true";
        $expiryactioned = "true";
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `wp_users` SET reminder_sent='$reminderSent', expiry_actioned='$expiryactioned' ");
    } elseif ($todayDate != $reminderDate && $reminderSent == false && $expiryActioned == true) { //    echo "Email is sent already ";
    }
}
//echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 day" , $todaysdate));
//}
```

I want to run the cron job in server and emails should be sent to the users after the day of registration , a week , 2 weeks. How can I write the script to call cron job.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Saurabh Hi pls find the php script....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a php script that checks how long has each user been registered. If it's first day, a week or second week of a user then send mail using mail() function or use any php mail library like swiftmailer.

Then run that php script everyday by assigning to crontab. 
Here's crontab config to run script "At 00:00 every day."
http://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*

Answer (score 0):

```
{   

    $url = "set email function url";
    $cSession = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    $result=curl_exec($cSession);
    curl_close($cSession);
    echo $result;

}
```

after that save this file and set that file path  on hosting server cron job  section 
i hope this code will you help
thanks